# django-parsley validations are not working

Tags: javascript, django, validation, client-side, parsley.js

I have done sever side validations in modelform and automatically generated HTML file for sign up form in my project now i want to convert it to client side validations..I'm trying to use parsley.js by just giving reference link..its rendering the correct files also but validations of parsley.js are not working..

please help me...
This is my mode class code:

```
<code>
 `class Organization(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, 
                        blank = False,  
                        null = False, 
                        help_text = "Please enter full name without abbreviations",
                        verbose_name = "Organization's Full Name:",
                        unique = True,
                        error_messages = 
                  {'unique': "Your organization has already signed up with us!" },
                        validators = [organization_name_validator],
                        )
    website = models.URLField(verbose_name = 'Website of your organization:',

    help_text = "Please enter the complete URL of your      organization's website",
                          null = True,
                          blank = True,
                         validators = [url_validator],
                          )
     #TODO: the following should have some custom phone number type of field
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=18,
                                blank = False,
                                null = False,

                                help_text = ""
                                verbose_name = "Official Phone Number",
                                unique = True,
                                error_messages = 
  {'unique' : 'Looks like an has already signed up!'},
                                validators = [phone_number_validator]
                                )

   registered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


  active = models.BooleanField(default = True,
                             verbose_name = 'Organization enabled ?',
                             help_text = ''
                              )

   signed_up_by_role = models.CharField(max_le ngth = 12,
                                    blank = False,
                                    null = False,
                                    verbose_name = ':',
                                    help_text = ""
                                   )


  def clean(self):

    if len(self.phone_number.strip()) == 0:
        raise ValidationError("Phone number cannot be empty.")


    if self.name.strip() == '':
        raise ValidationError("Name cannot be empty.")

   def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name`
```

this is my rendered html file which i have modified for parsley integration purpose  :

```
</code>   
<b>

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
    <title> {% block title %}Welcome to laresumex!{% endblock %}</title>
<script language='javascript' src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.1.0.js' %}"> </script>
    <script language='javascript' src="{% static 'js/parsley.min.js' %}"> </script>
<style type='text/css'>
        ul.parsley-error-list {
            font-size: 11px;
            margin: 2px;
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        ul.parsley-error-list li {
            line-height: 11px;
            color: #b94a48;
            background: #f2dede;
            border: 1px solid #eed3d7;
        }   
        $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#demo-form').parsley()
  });

</style>



</head>
<body>

 {% block body_block %}
<div class="hero-unit">
<h1>Organization signup form</h1>        
<div class="container">
<form id='form' data-parsley-validate method="post" >
{# cross-site-request-forgery-prevention #}
{% csrf_token %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} 
         {# we have to use field.field here because of visible_fields overlay #}
        {% if field.field.required %}
            <sup>*</sup>
        {% endif %}
        <sub>{{ field.help_text }}</sub>
        <br/>{{ field.errors }}

{% endfor %} 

    {# Include the hidden fields #}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{# Include the visible fields #}

<div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Signup!" /></p>
</div>

</form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>'
</b>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you have put parsley initialisation inside the style tag. Put it inside a script tag.

```
  <style type='text/css'>
    ul.parsley-error-list {
        font-size: 11px;
        margin: 2px;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    ul.parsley-error-list li {
        line-height: 11px;
        color: #b94a48;
        background: #f2dede;
        border: 1px solid #eed3d7;
    }
 </style>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#demo-form').parsley()
    });
 </script>
```